# is it feasible to use Oracle as my test Identity Provider - SAML

Tags: oracle, saml-2.0, opensaml

I am using SAML2.0 Protocol and I want to be a Service provider at my side.

I am using opensaml library to construct my provider. I am in need of a Identity Provider to test my set up.

Can I use Oracle as my Test Identity Provider ? Is it free to use ? I am already using salesforce as my test Idp. I need another Idp to test.

Summary :

Can I use Oracle SAML2.0 as Identity Provider to test my Service Provider? If not suggest me someother which is configurable basically.

EDIT: If Oracle can be used , could anyone please suggest the way to configure it?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open, free to use basic Idp at http://stubidp.kentor.se. It will allow accept AuthnRequests from any source and reply back to the assertion consumer service URL specified in the AuthnRequest. Currently it can only provide a Subject NameId, but if that is enough it is a simple test solution.

*Disclosure notice: I'm the author of the stubidp, but I won't make any money out of anyone using it, it's provided entirely as a free service.*

Comment: TO which Url should I send my SAMLRequest message , Relay State and all? I meant the Idp side HttpRedirect URL.

Comment: Directly to http://stubidp.kentor.se. Unfortunately there is no support for relay state (yet).

Comment: Are you also verifying the certificate if samlRequest has it? 
Generally in SAML , why is it like sharing the certificates mutually between SP and IdP , even though we are embedding them it in the Saml Request/Response message? THanks

Comment: No, the signature of the `AuthnRequest` is ignored. In fact, the intention with the stub idp is to let it ignore a lot of security measures to make testing easier.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is not free and is not trivial to install / configure.

You could install [Shibboleth](https://shibboleth.net/), [SimpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/) or look at [SSO Circle](http://www.ssocircle.com/en/).